# suggest web server monitoring service

Tags: monitoring, web-hosting, uptime

Please, suggest web server(web site, web hosting) monitoring service.

It should :
- be online
- monitor from different locations
- monitor uptime, response time etc.
- have alerts

Comment: Shopping Questions and product recommendations are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements do not list transaction monitoring, but I think that is important nowadays and narrows down your choice considerably. So if you also want to test if your site *really* works (aka "web application transaction monitoring") have a look at Alert*Fox*, Alert*Site* or Webmetrics. The later has good reporting but is very expensive. AlertFox has a useful free plan.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.pingdom.com/ is my favorite of these that exist. Free for 1 website as well.

Comment: also has an iPhone app which is great for checking on the go.

Comment: This is not free now. The pricing starts from 12EUR/mo.
You may give https://www.statuscake.com/ a try

Answer (score 0):

For basic pinging, AreMySitesUp is worth a look - http://aremysitesup.com/

Not sure about services that log uptime etc

Answer (score 0):

There are many services which do this another being - http://www.siteuptime.com/ - I think for the features you require its going to cost a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I learned to set up and run nagios.  I would recommend putting the time in and setting it up.  It really is a valuable tool for alerting you to network and host problems.  You can run it remotely on  a server for ~$30 a month per server on a server contracted with your favorite hosting service.

Comment: yes, I know that is a great tool, but I need simple interface, so every manager can use it